# Need help transforming code to work with strings rather than integers

Tags: java, string

In an older post, I asked for help with this problem:

Given a StringBuilder of a text file with formatting A [1, 2, 3, 4] B [5, 6, 7, 8] C [9, 10]

I need to create a method so that when given the text file's name, and a token to search i.e. "StringBuilder ex.txt" and "A", respectively,it will return a list with elements 1, 2, 3, and 4.

This code worked

```
static List<Double> getElements(String fileContent, String token) {
  StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(fileContent));
  List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
  while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
    if (tokenizer.sval.equals(token)) {
      tokenizer.nextToken();  // '[' 
      do {
        tokenizer.nextToken();  // go to the number
        list.append(tokenizer.nval);
      } while (tokenizer.nextToken() == ',');
      break;
    }
  } 
  return list;
}
```

Now I'm trying to adapt that code to work on something like word1 [yzh, ppk, edf] word2 [ift, yyu, atb]

Below is my attempt:

```
public List<String> getPhrases(StringBuilder fileContent, String token) {
      StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(fileContent.toString()));
      List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
      while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
        if (tokenizer.sval.equals(token)) {
          tokenizer.nextToken();  // '[' 
          do {
            tokenizer.nextToken();  // go to the number
            list.append(String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval));
          } while (tokenizer.nextToken() == ',');
          break;
        }
      } 
      return list;
    }
```

The problem is that the append method returns an error of being undefined for the type List.  How can this situation be remedied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead this `String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval)` use `tokenizer.sval` and use 'list.add (sval)'.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried all combinations of n/sval and String.valueOf, and it's been to no avail.

Comment: What if you try to use  'list.add (sval)' instead 'list.append (sval)'?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
 list.append(String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval));
```

I think you want:

```
 list.append(tokenizer.sval);
```